# How do I restrict a generic type to specific types in java?

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class with a generic variable. I want to restrict that variable to a set
of types (like Car, Bike, ...) as shown below:

```
class Garage{
   Class<K> ownerStaff;

   public Garage(Car c){
      this.ownerStaff = c;
   }
   public Garage(Bike b){
      this.ownerStaff = b;
   }
   ...
}
```

So the "genericVariable" can be only a Car, a Bike or any other type I want but not anything. How can I do something like that?

**Note:**
I think I can make a parent class "Vehicle" and then write it that way (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
class Garage<K extends Vehicle>{
   Class<K> ownerStaff;

   public Garage(Class<K> c){
      this.ownerStaff = c;
   }
}
```

but I don't want a parent class and make all my classes extends "Vehicle" and may I don't want to type e.g. `Garage<Car>` when I instantiate a "Garage".

Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be generic? It can just be type `Vehicle`. Make `Vehicle` an interface instead of a class if your types don't share common code.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `K` not `Class<K>`. `Class<K>` is mostly used for reflection.

Comment: Yes I probably mean K. Never mind ...
If I make an interface Vehicle then I write the second piece of code right? I mean ... Garage<K extends Vehicle>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're objects eventually have to have some sort of common behavior, or else it wouldn't make sense to place them in the same `Garage`. So as @perelman suggested, simply declare this common behavior in an interface and use that (no generics):

```
public interface Vehicle {
    // common behavior declared, if any
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
    // Implementation
}

public class Bike implements Vehicle {
    // Implementation
}

public class Garage {
    Vehicle vehicle;

    public Garage(Vehicle v) {
       vehicle = v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rereading your question, what I think you want is simply have the `ownerStaff` field be of type `Class<?>`. This allows you to fill it with any Class instance regardless of its type.

<sub>Old answer here: The only way to restrict the generic type is using `<K extends Vehicle>` as you've already said. This has the added advantage of being able to call all `Vehicle` methods on the instances of `K` in your class.</sub>

<sub>You could of course just do an `instanceof` check on the value type, for example, in your constructor, add `if (!(Car.class.isAssignableFrom(c) or Bike.class.isAssignableFrom(c))) throw new IllegalArgumentException("we only accept cars and bikes")`. This would be a quite restrictive check though, and prevent users of the class from inventing their own vehicle type.</sub>

Comment: I think you're right with Class<?>, but `this.ownerStuff = c;` doesn't work (incompatible types Class<?> and Car).

Answer (score 1):

Since Java doesn't have algebraic data types - i.e. you can't say "type A or type B", only "type A and B", through common supertypes - this isn't something you can naturally do.

One way to work around this would be to make the constructor of `Garage` private and only provide static factory methods for particular types:

```
class Garage<K> {
    private Garage<K>(K thing) { this.thing = thing; } // hidden
    private K thing;
    public Garage<Car> newCarGarage(Car c) {
        return new Garage<Car>(c);
    }
    //... similarly for other types you want to be allowed
}
```