# How can java function adopt various parameter types by template or something else?

Tags: java, templates, polymorphism

I tried to implement a function adaptive to different Buffer types, such as ByteBuffer, IntBuffer, FloatBuffer and etc. The pseudo code was show as followed

```
<T1, T2> boolean compareBuffer(T1 buf1, T1 buf2) {
    if(buf1.capacity() != buf2.capacity()) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < buf1.capacity(); i++) {
        T2 v1 = buf1.get(i);
        T2 v2 = buf2.get(i);
        if(v1 != v2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The compiler reported errors. How can I do this in a simple way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restrict a generic type to specific types in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239343/how-do-i-restrict-a-generic-type-to-specific-types-in-java)

Comment: There is no way to do this in Java.  Primitives don't work with the generic system, nor do they work well with the class system (autoboxing helps a bit).  Basically no approaches are "simple" here.  So how much complexity are you willing to tolerate?  And why do you need to compare buffers?

Comment: The posted pseudo code needs further clarity: you pass in two parameters of type `T1` but then use `get` and expect both to return values of type `T2` ?  In general, is the comparison limited to buffers of the same type - it would seem it must?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point.  But primitives will auto-promote.  So perhaps the OP is expecting that?

Comment: Actually my code used different Buffers, some of them origniated from JNI code
and I wanted to use compareBuffer to check data consistency. And there were
similar buffer setting and dumping functions for debugging purposes. For these
function I would prefer code implementation simplicity to runtime time cost
since they were only called in debug versions. @markspace

Comment: T2 would be int, float (or Integer, Float) based on T1. @Andy

Comment: What Andy was asking was if T2 would ever be different from T1.  Could T1 be `int` and T2 `float` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand about [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java.

In your case, the compiler has no information about the types T1 and T2, except that they must be descendants of Object, because all reference types are.    Thus you can only use attributes and methods of Object in the body of compareBuffer.

It appears you expect T1 and T2 to implement the Buffer interface. Therefore declare:

```
  <T1 extends Buffer, T2 extends Buffer> boolean compareBuffer(T1 buf1, T1 buf2)
```

Now you can use attributes and methods of Buffer.

Comment: The method `get()` doesn't appear on the `Buffer` abstract class.  And the concrete classes return a primitive.  So... no dice.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was focused on the class types, not on the lines that expect to extract individual elements via 'get'.

Comment: And I misread it twice, thinking that the two buffers had different types T1 and T2.